# 巡回冗長検査 (CRC) エラーなのに画像ビューアで表示できた場合、データは壊れていないのですか？

Tags: windows, 画像

**現状**
・Windows10で(.CR2拡張子の)ファイルコピーしようとしたら巡回冗長検査 (CRC) エラーとなりました
・しかしHoneyview(画像ビューア)ソフトウェアで開いたら普通に画像表示されました

---

**質問**
・ソフトウェアで画像表示された、ということはファイルは壊れていないのですか？
※これまで巡回冗長検査 (CRC) エラーが出た場合、データが壊れたと思いファイル削除していました
・ファイル表示できてもファイルコピー出来ないことはあり得るのですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRC は単純に巡回冗長検査で、いろんなところで使われています。ファイルをコピーしただけで CRC エラーが出るということなら、ハードディスクや SSD など記憶メディア上でハードウェアが自動で行っている CRC 検査に失敗したということです。

ディスク装置上、セクタは 512byte や 4096byte などのペイロード（純粋にユーザが登録したいデータ）と、付随する何らかの情報（ CRC 値とかセクタ番号とか）から構成されているので、セクタ内部のどこかが誤っているということになりそうです。

- ファイルの内容は壊れているの？

壊れていると考えてよいです。原因はハードディスク自体（メモリカード自体）にあるので、対策は当該ディスクやカードをお役御免にする事（新しいカードげっちゅ）になるでしょう。特にハードディスクだと原因がプラッタの傷だったりしますが、この場合エラーがだんだん増える傾向にありますのでサクッと入れ替えたいところです。

- 壊れていても表示できるの？

`.CR2` はキャノンの RAW 形式データのようですから、数バイト化けていたとしても特定位置の数ドットの色がほんの少し変化している程度で見ただけではわからないレベルでおさまっていることが多そうです。 jpg 変換したら失われる程度の差かもしれません。

Comment: やはり壊れているのですね。たまたま最初に試したCRCエラー画像が正常表示された(ように見えた)ので驚いて質問しました。その後、別のCRCエラー画像も何枚か試してみたのですが、何れもうまくいかなかった(一部表示やフリーズ）ので、やはり壊れているのだと思いました…

Comment: 記憶装置の CRC 異常は書いた通り物理的損傷が原因な場合が多いので、データが拾えるうちに装置交換をお勧めします。っていうかバックアップはやはり大事です。今のうちに複数メディアに複写しておきましょう。