# Windowsで、(ファイル移動やコピーを行わずに)巡回冗長検査 (CRC) エラーが発生するファイルの一覧を確認したい

Tags: windows

Windowsで、巡回冗長検査 (CRC) エラーが発生するファイルの一覧を確認したいのですが、どうすればよいですか？

巡回冗長検査 (CRC) エラーが発生するファイル名を確認したいだけなので、コピーや移動は実行したくありません。
コピーや移動を行わず、CRCエラーだけを確認する方法があれば処理が速く済むのではと思い質問しました。

Comment: 宣伝を兼ねているのでしょうが、こんな記事があります。[「CRCエラーというメッセージが表示され、重要なデータが確認できない…」CRCエラーの原因と修復する方法は？](https://www.buffalo.jp/topics/trouble/detail/124143886_1538.html) 他にもこんなのが。[Does Windows calculate CRCs to check every file operation?](https://superuser.com/q/566113), [Does NTFS store the hash or CRC32 of every inode/file, how to access it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53457086/9014308), [「chkdsk」と修復オプション](https://pctrouble.net/running/chkdsk.html)

Comment: 別系統としてはこれらの記事でしょうか。[ハードディスク/SSDのSMART情報を確認する](https://pctrouble.net/storage/smart_check.html), [SMART情報と不良セクタ](https://pctrouble.net/storage/smart_badsector.html), [不良セクタのあるハードディスクへの対応](https://pctrouble.net/storage/hdd_badsector.html), こちらは前コメントの系統かと。[ファイルまたはディレクトリが壊れているため、読み取ることができません](https://pctrouble.net/running/corrupted_directory.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CRCエラーは通常発生しません。一般的にはハードウェア故障状態です。ファイルを実際に読み出しを行う際、エラーが発生したことを意味します。ですので読み出しを行わなければCRCエラーが発生するかはわかりませんし、一度発生しても回復することもあります。
質問のCRCエラーが発生することをむやみに確認する行為は、逆に故障時期を早めることがあります。 [`chkdsk`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk) など専用のツールに任せるべきです。

もしご自身でファイルシステムの修復ツールを実装するのであれば[Windows NT ファイルシステム詳説](https://www.oreilly.co.jp/books/4900900702/)などが参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: 不良セクタの確認ではなく、読込出来ないファイル名を確認したかっただけなのですが。そんな簡単な話ではないのですね…

Comment: ハードディスク装置の CRC エラーはプラッタの傷が原因のことが多いです。ハードディスク装置のほうで読み込みのリトライをすれば２度目、３度目には読めたりしますので、発生したり収まったりするのは普通の話。あとその傷がファイル内容でなく管理領域にあると「特定ファイル１個が読めない」で済まなくなったりします。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48868/ 時点から同じ物理装置を使い続けているんでしょうか？　さっくり交換を推奨っす。

Comment: 「一度発生しても回復することもあります」「プラッタの傷が原因のことが多いです。ハードディスク装置のほうで読み込みのリトライをすれば２度目、３度目には読めたりします」が良く分からないです。物理的に傷がついているのに、何回か試すと読み込めたりするのですか？　「プラッタに傷」がついているのに読み込むと、さらに傷が広がる可能性がある、という説明なら分かるのですが。CRCエラーは、プラッタの傷か否かで対応が分かれる、ということですか？　「同じ物理装置を使い続けているんでしょうか？」交換しました。別の物理装置の話です。今回も交換する予定ですが、その前に、問題ファイル名を突き止めたいのです。ファイル名を突き止めさえすればバックアップから復元できるので。

Comment: オイラもハードディスクの専門家ではないので話半分に訊いてほしいのですが、傷と言っても目には見えない程度の磁性体のかすかな剥がれだと読み込んだ S/N 極性が閾値ぎりぎりにあったりするそうです。たまたま熱雑音が小さいと正常に読めて、大きいと CRC 異常になるとのこと。なので微小な傷でとどまっている限りは運が絡む話であるらしいです。プラッタとヘッドの物理接触があるとご理解の通り、破片によって傷が広がっていくのですが、そこまでいかないレベルとのこと。

Answer (score 1):

役立つ記事かもしれません。

CRCエラー（巡回冗長検査エラー）を修復する方法
https://jp.minitool.com/data-recovery/data-error-crc.html

Comment: 「紛失されたファイルを表示」という機能があるようなので、「読込エラーファイル名の特定」に該当するかもしれない、と思いました。

Answer (score 1):

NTFS パーティションなら、nfi.exe ツールを使えばファイルを特定できると思います。

LBAからNTFSのファイルを特定する1
http://liliumrubellum.blog10.fc2.com/blog-entry-331.html

Comment: NTFSかどうか分からなかったので、「ディスクの管理」画面で確認してみました。該当HDDも含め全てのHDDが「NTFS」でした。

Comment: だったら、"HDD-Scan" 等のフリーウェアで不良セクタのアドレスを確認し、その上で nfi ツールで該当セクタを調べれば、そのセクタを使用しているファイルを特定できると思います。
なお該当セクタに対応するファイルは必ずしも Explorer 上で確認できるファイルとは限らない (meta-file, journal file, etc.) ので、その点はご注意ください。